# passportjs TypeError: User.authenticate is not a function

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js, typeerror, passport-local

I'm trying to build a small nodejs, express, mongodb app with authentication using passport-local and passport-local-mongoose, however for some reason when entering the middleware for passport in the main app.js file I get this error "TypeError: User.authenticate is not a function"

I tried the authentication by itself in a test project and it worked just fine, so maybe it's something to do with the order of my code but I can't get to what's causing this issue. I've tried several refactors but to no avail.

Below is the code for the app.js and the User Schema , but [Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/czb5jixrkqye9aq/vidjot.zip?dl=0) a link to the project files if needed.

app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  path = require('path'),
  exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
  methodOverride = require('method-override'),
  flash = require('connect-flash'),
  session = require('express-session'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
  passport = require("passport"),
  mongodb = require("mongodb"),
  User = require("./models/User");

// Load routes
const ideas = require('./routes/ideas');
const users = require('./routes/users');

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/diaries');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

// Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Method override middleware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Express session midleware
//PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret: "secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const title = 'Welcome';
  res.render('index', {
    title: title
  });
});

// About Route
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about');
});


// Use routes
app.use('/ideas', ideas);
app.use('/users', users);

const port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

User Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: "email"});
mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

try importing `LocalStrategy` from `require('passport-local').Strategy`

like 
`const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy`